# Oracle count(*) returns different value for aggregate functions

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone explain why the same query returns a different count depending on if an aggregate function is used?

```
--Returns 1
select count(*) from
(
    select min(date_field) from mytable where field1 = 'xxx'
)

--Returns 0
select count(*) from
(
    select * from mytable where field1 = 'xxx'
)
```

Comment: First one counts records where `field1` is NOT `'xxx'` and the second one counts records where `field1` IS `'xxx'`.

Comment: they don't look like the same query. = vs !=

Comment: you're totally right, added a 'better' example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a `GROUP BY` clause, the query:

```
select min(date_field) from mytable where field1 = 'xxx'
```

always returns exactly one row, no matter how many rows of the table match the `WHERE` clause.

The lack of the `GROUP BY` clause forces the engine to create only one group from the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause, therefore it returns one row. When there are no rows in the group, the expression `min(date_field)` evaluates to `NULL`.

On the other hand, the query:

```
select * from mytable where field1 = 'xxx'
```

produces zero or more rows (the rows that match the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: Thanks.  I see how the min query (#1) returns 0 rows when I add a `group by field1` statement.

Comment: Practice without the outer `select count(*)` to see what results you get for each query with `WHERE` conditions that match some rows or don't match any row.